# How can I get the active menu trail for the current page?

Tags: 8

If I use [Drupal::menuTree()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3AmenuTree/8) to load a menu it seems to always have inActiveTrail set to FALSE for all my items.

As an example consider the following code:

```
$menu_tree = Drupal::menuTree();
$parameters = new MenuTreeParameters();
$parameters->setTopLevelOnly();
$main_menu_top_level = $menu_tree->load('main', $parameters);
```

That code returns the top level of the main menu with inActiveTrail = FALSE for all items regardless of what page I am on.

I believe [MenuTreeParameters::setActiveTrail()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Menu!MenuTreeParameters.php/function/MenuTreeParameters%3A%3AsetActiveTrail/8) is meant to help here but then I have to pass in an active trail.

How do I get the active menu trail for the current page load so I can then pass it in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`MenuLinkTreeInterface::getCurrentRouteMenuTreeParameters()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Menu!MenuLinkTreeInterface.php/function/MenuLinkTreeInterface%3A%3AgetCurrentRouteMenuTreeParameters/8) is what you want. To use the example above:

```
$menu_tree = Drupal::menuTree();
$parameters = $menu_tree->getCurrentRouteMenuTreeParameters('main');
$parameters->setTopLevelOnly();
$main_menu_top_level = $menu_tree->load('main', $parameters);
```

The resulting menu tree should have `inActiveTrail` flagged.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be exactly what I was looking for, although in the example I would replace the new MenuTreeParameters() line with your new getCurrentRouteMenuTreeParameters() line instead of putting it below the setTopLevelOnly() call.

Comment: Makes sense. That was a quick copy/paste job. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Use the active menu trail service, `menu.active_trail`, returns `\Drupal\Core\Menu\MenuActiveTrailInterface`. You can then use it to identify the active trail(s), and then retrieve it from the menu tree(s). Saves a foreach loop over the various menu items and testing for `inActiveTrail`.

`$ids = $this->activeTrail->getActiveTrailIds('main');
$parameters = (new MenuTreeParameters())->setActiveTrail($ids);
$tree = $this->linkTree->load('main', $parameters);
$active = $tree[reset($ids)]; // There may be more than one...`